# DefaultValueHandling not honored in Json.NET 4.5

Tags: .net, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET 4.5 and following this [blog post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx), trying to get my user objects to serialize correctly.

I've been beating my head against the wall for hours; no matter what I do, I cannot get Json.NET to ignore ints when they are set to the "default unitialized value for that value type", aka 0.

```
[DataContract]    
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email{ get; set; }        
}
```

Here's the call to serialize it:

```
var user = new User()
{
    Id = 0,
    Name = "John Doe",
    Email = null
}

string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
});
```

The resulting JSON is:

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "John Doe"
}
```

Email is omitted because it is null. Id should be omitted because it is 0. I have also tried explicitly setting the [DefaultValue(0)] attribute on Id, to no effect.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

### Update

After taking another look, DefaultValueAtribute **is** being honored for ints. So this code will result Ids of 0 not being serialized.

```
[DataContract]    
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email{ get; set; }        
}
```

Not the stated behavior, but at least it allows me to get on with my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug. According to [the example from documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) a DefaultValueAttribute shouldn't be required. This is useful e.g. when you can't edit the type you're serializing.

I made [an issue in Github](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/38) for it, along with a patch/hack (against 4.5r8).